# Rails Json Response is Not Rendered in Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

Code of controller abcd
..............................

```
respond_to :html, :json 

def index

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
format.json  { render :msg=>"comment oK"}
end
```

code of  javascript 
.................................

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#button').click(function(){

$.ajax({
   type    : 'POST',
   dataType: 'script',
    url     : "http://localhost:3000/abcd/index", 
    data    : {  },
    processData:false,
     error :  function(xhr, status) {

        }, 
     complete: function(data) {
          alert(data.msg);
           },  

 success : function(data) {
          window.alert("it worked");        
        },  

        });

  return false;
    });

  });
```

In the above code when i click button , only alert(data.msg);  works and it gives alert Undefined . why it happens and what is the problem ?? why comment ok is not shwoing in Pop up alert ??

Comment: try to access data["msg"]

Comment: In order to get the response as json, it is standard practice to append the url with ```.json```. Try calling ```http://localhost:3000/abcd/index.json``` instead, and rails will do it's magic.

Comment: Neither data['msg'] or  http://localhost:3000/abcd/index.json works

Answer (score 0):

For `dataType: 'script'` you need: `format.js`

You can also change the dataType to `dataType: 'json'`